# PG Error - Data Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, type-mismatch

```
Failures:

  1) POST /v1/notes/id saves the lat, lon, note text, note photo, recipients, and expiration
   Failure/Error: post '/v1/notes', {
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
     LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (45) LIMIT 1
                                                  ^
     : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (45) LIMIT 1
```

I'm assuming that the following method should Find or create a user object, but for some reason I'm getting the above Error.

```
def create
  @note = Note.new(note_params)
    if @note.save
    render
  end
end

private
def note_params
    { 
    #user_id: params[:user_id],
    user_id: user[:id],
    lat: params[:lat],
    lon: params[:lon],
    note_text: params[:note_text],
    photo_uri: params[:photo_uri],
    expiration: params[:expiration]
    }
 end


 def user
   user = User.find_or_create_by(params[:user_id])
 end
```

I'm assuming that you'd want to use the `user` method to create or find a User object based on the user_id that would go into the `note_params`, but not clear on the difference between using `user_id: user[:id]` instead of `#user_id: params[:user_id]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `user` method. You need to provide a hash with the attributes needed for finding or creating a `user`in your database.

```
def user
   user = User.find_or_create_by(id: params[:user_id])
end
```

With `params[:user_id]` you are getting the id of the user right from the params hash. With `user[:id]` you are calling the `user` method that returns an user object, then retrieves its id (You could just call `user.id`)